# ng-checked no funciona

Tags: angularjs

Tengo lo sgte :

```
$scope.query = {};
$scope.schemas = [{field:'test1'},{field:'test2'},{field:'test3'}] 

<div ng-repeat="(indexX,schema) in schemas">
  <input type="radio" ng-model="query[indexX].test" value="{{schema.field}}"/>

  <input type="checkbox" value="{{schema.field}}" 
          ng-init="query[indexX][column.field].check=false" 
          ng-model="query[indexX][schema.field].check" 
          ng-checked="query[indexX].test"/> 
</div>
```

El problema es que cuando le doy al radio se seleccionan todos los checkbox

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de datos de entrada? He intentado reproducir tu problema pero se me hace bastante complejo reproducir tus datos.

Comment: editado, supongo que me pedias eso

Comment: Sí, era eso, ¿Y `query`? Precisamente `query` es lo que más me cuesta reproducir.

Comment: realmente es mucho mas grande el html, pero resumido es así, modificado

Comment: He intentado reproducir el problema (más o menos). Aunque no me pasa exactamente lo que describes. Mira mi respuesta por si puedes ayudarme, dime cómo debe comportarse, dime qué debería pasar al pulsar cada botón para que sepa si lo que está pasando está bien o hay que corregirlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que puedas seleccionar únicamente uno de los `radio` debes tener un nombre común en todos ellos. En caso contrario conforme vayas pulsando uno tras otro los `radio` éstos se activarán y se quedará así de manera permanente.

```js
var stackApp = angular.module('stackApp', []);
stackApp
  .controller('Ejemplo',
    ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.test = 'OK';
      $scope.query = {};
      $scope.schemas = [
        { field:'test1' },
        { field:'test2' },
        { field:'test3' }
      ];
    }]
);
angular.bootstrap(document, ['stackApp']);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form ng-controller="Ejemplo">
  <div ng-repeat="(indexX,schema) in schemas">
    <p>{{test}} ({{indexX}})</p>
    <input name="seleccion" type="radio"
      ng-model="query[schema.field].test"
      ng-value="true"/>
    <input type="checkbox"
      ng-value="schema.field"
      ng-init="query[schema.field].test = false"
      ng-model="query[schema.field].test"
      ng-checked="query[schema.field].test"/>
  </div>
  <pre>
    {{query | json}}
  </pre>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://bentorfs.github.io/angular-bootstrap-multiselect/bower_components/angular-bootstrap-multiselect/dist/angular-bootstrap-multiselect.min.js"></script>
```

Te he agregado un volcado del estado de la aplicación para que puedas depurar lo que está pasando y decidas si es lo que debería ocurrir.

Comment: ahora mismo no puedo probarlo, pero lo unico que has añadido es el atributo name?

Comment: Sí, para agrupar los `radio` en un único grupo (para que sólo uno quede seleccionado). Usa "Página completa" tras darle a "Ejecutar" para ver la información de depuración mejor.

Comment: He detectado que había índices mal expresados, por lo que los datos se guardaban en los campos que no eran, espero que esta edición cierre un poco más el cerco sobre la solución (aunque aún no sé qué pretendes conseguir, estoy arreglando errores a ciegas).

Comment: gracias que me faltaba el name

Comment: De nada, un placer. Recuerda marcar la respuesta correcta si fue la que solucionó el problema, gracias.

Comment: ya lo habia marcado, si sabes algo de websphere he abierto una pregunta :)

Comment: De Java y tomcat sí. En mi empresa usan websphere y weblogic y allí hay desplegadas algunas de mis aplicaciones, veré si puedo ayudarte en algo